# How to renumber lines using a vi command?

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I am trying to renumber the lines `2,$` in a file using vim a command, I know the command `cat -n` of nl, I can number the lines, but I didn't get the expected output:

I tried this  `:2,$s/^\([^,]\)// | 2,$!cat -n`

input:

```
#,Name,Types,Total,HP,Attack,Weaknesses,Strength
493,Arceus,Normal,720,120,120,Fighting,strong
483,Dialga,Steel;Dragon,680,100,120,Fighting;Ground,strong
250,Ho-oh,Fire;Flying,680,106,130,Electric;Water;Rock,strong
.... moer 100 lines
```

expected output:

```
#,Name,Types,Total,HP,Attack,Weaknesses,Strength
1,Arceus,Normal,720,120,120,Fighting,strong
2,Dialga,Steel;Dragon,680,100,120,Fighting;Ground,strong
3,Ho-oh,Fire;Flying,680,106,130,Electric;Water;Rock,strong
....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\=` to use a `sub-replace-expression`, and `line('.')` to get the current line number:

```
" The parenthesis around `line('.')-1` are not needed, but it seems clearer to me
:2,$s/^/\=(line('.')-1).','/
```

---

Edit: just realized you're actually replacing your first column, so you might actually want

```
:2,$s/^\d\+/\=line('.')-1/
```